# Why can't a time-varying charge density cause magnetic field according to Jefimenko's equations?

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose there is a time-varying charge density $\rho$, e. g. $\rho=\rho_{0}sin(\omega t)$, which leads to a time-varying electric field. According to Jefimenko's equation for magnetic field, $\rho$ doesn't create any magnetic field, since that equation only depends on a current density $J$, not a charge density. On the other hand, Ampere's law says a time varying electric field does create a magnetic field! How's that possible?

Comment: How is your charge density varying? Seems like you can't have varying charge density without a current.

Comment: I'm thinking of a static point charge $q$ which somehow changes in time. Or a static sphere with a time-varying total charge q, and a homogeneous charge density $\rho=q/V$.

Comment: Electrodynamics requires conservation of charge. So you can't just make charges appear and disappear. To change charge density, you have to move charges around, and that means a current.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm thinking of a static point charge q which somehow changes in time.

If that were possible, without an associated current, electric charge would not be conserved.  Further, such a time varying point charge source would produce monopole radiation.

Don't forget the Maxwell-Ampere law:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{H} = \mathbf{J}_f + \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t}$$

Taking the divergence of both sides yields

$$\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{H}) = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}_f + \nabla \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t}$$

$$0 =  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}_f + \frac{\partial(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D})}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}_f + \frac{\partial \rho_f}{\partial t}$$

and so the "somehow changes in time" is necessarily due to a non-zero current.

Answer (score 1):

The current density $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x},t)=\rho(\mathbf{x},t) \mathbf{v_d}(\mathbf{x},t)$ is dependent on the charge density. Having a time-dependent charge density requires having a time-dependent current density.